# Regex: how to match a formatted number?

Tags: regex

I have written the following regex

```
(?<=\bUSD\s)([+-]?((\d+\.?\d*)|(\.\d+)))
```

It returns the number after a currency, so if we have `123.5 USD`, it will return `123.5`, it can be tested [here](https://regex101.com/)

I want to make a few modifications to the regex, sometimes we receive numbers formatted like this:

1. a `'` formatted number `USD 1’750.00`
2. or a space formatted number `USD 1 753.00`
3. or a comma formatted number `USD 1,753.00`
4. or the currency is after the number `1’750.00 USD`
5. I'd like the regex to return 2 values: the amount `$1` and the currency `$2`
6. It would be awesome also if the regex can support multiple currencies, but if not that's okay.

Comment: Hi. What is the flavor of your regex? Also, your attached link has no special case link.

Comment: @albina, regarding the flavor, I'm using pure regex, no programming language, whatever works [here](https://regex101.com) will work for me because I'm using a platform called male.com to handle the programming part. And here's a special case link https://regex101.com/r/qgKwWx/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(\d+[’.,\s]\d+[.]\d+|\d+[.,\s]\d+)|(USD|CAD|CDF)`

There are 2 groups:

- `(USD|CAD|CDF)` matches a currency (here you can list different currencies)
- `(\d+[’.,\s]\d+[.]\d+|\d+[.,\s]\d+)` matches numbers in different formats, covers all the cases with numbers you mentioned

  - `\d+[.,\s]\d+` matches numbers like `123.4`
  - `\d+[’.,\s]\d+[.]\d+` includes other cases like `1 753.00`

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YGwDLq/1)